# System.out.println is causing stackoverflow error

Tags: java, stack-overflow

I am writing a program to solve RUSH HOUR problem available at code chef

I am using DFS to solve the problem. In DFS's recursive function, I am printing message based on DEBUG variable.

First of all ***DEBUG*** variable is set ***false***

There is one Car Class

```
class Car {
    boolean isVertical;
    char c;
    int x;
    int y;
    int length;

    public Car(boolean val, char ch, int i, int j, int l) {
        c = ch;
        isVertical = val;
        x = i;
        y = j;
        length = l;
    }
}
```

// DFS recursive functions

```
private int findPath(int carId, int index) {
        if (isPathCleared()) {
            answerFound = true;
            return index;
        }
        
        Car car = carArray[carId];
        
        if (DEBUG)
            System.out.println("car id:   " + (char)(index+'A'));
            
        // some lines of code
        call to findPath()
}
```

or

```
private int findPath(int carId, int index) {
        if (isPathCleared()) {
            answerFound = true;
            return index;
        }
        
        Car car = carArray[carId];
        
        if (DEBUG)
            System.out.println("car id:   " + car.c);
            
        // some lines of code
        call to findPath()

}
```

Above recursive functions throw ***java.lang.StackOverflowError***

But below recursive functions work fine

```
private int findPath(int carId, int index) {
        if (isPathCleared()) {
            answerFound = true;
            return index;
        }
        
        Car car = carArray[carId];
        
        if (DEBUG)
            System.out.println("just string message");
            
        // some lines of code
        call to findPath()

}
```

or

```
private int findPath(int carId, int index) {
        if (isPathCleared()) {
            answerFound = true;
            return index;
        }
        
        Car car = carArray[carId];
        
        if (DEBUG)
            System.out.println("car id:   " + (index+100));
            
        // some lines of code
        call to findPath()

}
```

Can anybody explain this behavior? Since it is written in false condition, it(System.out.println() call) should not go on stack.

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with your system.out at all. You say that your findPath method calls itself at the end. Is there an end condition where it doesn't cal itself?

Comment: What makes you think it is System.out.println? What line is the stack trace pointing at?

Comment: or place a breakpoint in your code and run your program in debug. Easy way to see where your code is stuck in a loop